# c++ std::async literally async with respect to thread assignment of tasks

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, std

I've successfully used std::async in the past, but lately in checking the fidelity of some new code, I've run into an oddity that has me stumped. I'm sure there should be a simple explanation and a proper solution, but I can't find a discussion of it anywhere.

The following bit of minimal code illustrates the matter:

```
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    for (size_t delay = 0; delay < 2; delay++) {
        std::vector<std::future<std::string>> futures;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, 
                [&i] () -> std::string
                {
                    std::stringstream ss;
                    ss << "work on number " << i << " " << std::this_thread::get_id();
                    return ss.str();
                }
            );
            if (delay == 1) {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
            }
            futures.push_back(std::move(fut));
        }

        // do not proceed until all threads are done
        std::for_each(futures.begin(), futures.end(), [](std::future<std::string>& fut) 
            {
                auto codeconf = fut.get();
                std::cout << codeconf << std::endl;
            }
        );
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Without the delay (i.e. first time through the outer loop), some loop-elements (integers) get missed and don't get assigned to a thread/task, while other loop elements get assigned to more than one thread. The loop also runs beyond it's limits:

work on number 4 139770383861504
work on number 4 139770375468800
work on number 4 139770367076096
work on number 6 139770358683392
work on number 5 139770350290688
work on number 6 139770341897984
work on number 7 139770333505280
work on number 8 139770325112576
work on number 10 139770248296192
work on number 10 139770239903488

Including a minor delay (10 ms) allows loop increments and threads to correspond as expected and intended -- i.e. a one-to-one correspondence between loop increment and task/thread (the order of completion doesn't matter, of course, even though they are in order here):

work on number 0 139770239903488
work on number 1 139770248296192
work on number 2 139770325112576
work on number 3 139770333505280
work on number 4 139770383861504
work on number 5 139770375468800
work on number 6 139770367076096
work on number 7 139770358683392
work on number 8 139770350290688
work on number 9 139770341897984

My understanding is that the async launch policy should just pick up the integer that corresponds to the loop iteration, feed it into the lambda function, and execute it on an independent task/thread; when it starts (which is essentially immediate) and when it ends doesn't really matter to the functioning and logic of the loop. But here, without a delay, "async" seems to quite literally to describe the relationship between loop iterations and tasks.

Is the tiny delay workaround legitimate? What am I failing to understand?

Comment: Can you try copying `i`, instead of capturing it by reference.  Accessing `i` on multiple threads could be a problem.

Comment: I'll be damned. Thank you! Simply changing [&i] to [i] in the lambda function achieves the expected behaviour without the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Without the delay (i.e. first time through the outer loop), some loop-elements (integers) get missed and don't get assigned to a thread/task, while other loop elements get assigned to more than one thread

This is an immediate red flag for trying to access a loop counter from another thread that was spawned in that loop.

In this case, your tasks use a *reference* to `i`, which is being incremented (and eventually destroyed) in the main thread.

You should pass a *copy* of `i` to each task, so that the task assuredly uses whatever the value of `i` was on that iteration.

Comment: weird.. there's been 3 threads this week where someone used `std::async` with capture by reference of loop counter causing UB, and before this week I'd never seen it

Answer (score 1):

As @RichardCritten said in the comments, having one thread (the main one) writing to `i` while other threads are reading it leads to undefined behaviour. I wouldn't try to figure out why the output is like it is, the compile can change the ordering of memory stores/writes can change at will without synchronisation (mutex's etc).

A couple of helpful talks on the subject:

- Herb Sutter's "atomic<> weapons": http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2
- Han's Boehm's "Threads and Shared Variables in C++11": http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Threads-and-Shared-Variables-in-C-11